# How to get most viewed articles that i was published between two dates using Google Analytics Java code?

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

I have written the below code. But it returns articles that have most views during the time between START_DATE and END_DATE. It might contain articles that were published long before START_DATE. But I don't want articles published before START_DATE. I need articles that were published between START_DATE and END_DATE, which got most views. Is there any option Google Analytics provided?

```
                AnalyticsService as = new AnalyticsService(appName);
                String token = credential.getAccessToken();
                as.setAuthSubToken(token);
                DataQuery query = new DataQuery(new URL(baseUrl));
                query.setIds("ga:" + propfileID);
                query.setDimensions("ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath,ga:pagePathLevel1,ga:pagePathLevel2,ga:pagePathLevel3,ga:hostname");
                query.setSegment("gaid::-11");
                query.setMetrics("ga:pageviews");
                query.setSort("-ga:pageviews");
                query.setMaxResults(20);
                query.setStartDate(GA_MOST_READ_START_DATE);
                query.setEndDate(GA_MOST_READ_END_DATE);
                URL url = query.getUrl();
                LOG.info("===GoogleAnalyticsScheduler===query==URL: " + url.toString());


                DataFeed feed = as.getFeed(url, DataFeed.class);
```

Comment: Now that you have edited the typo in your question after i have answered it please add the value of url and the data that is being returned.

Comment: sorry. setEndDate(GA_MOST_READ_START_DATE); is a typing mistake.
The values returned is some urls only

Comment: Please edit your question and add the results.